# How should I disable elements that programmed for hover in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I have some divs that when you hover the mouse over them, some text will appear.
Now in a situation, I want to move my div from position a , to position b, but I want to deactive hover for them, that mean when you hover this animated div, the text don't come appear!!

and I need a condition that if the divs came back to the first position, the hover function become active again...

would you give me some suggestions for this???

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseenter', '#p20', function(){

    $('#enroll-en').fadeIn(5).animate({
        marginTop: 150 }, 'fast', false);

    $('#enroll-fa').fadeIn(5).animate({
        marginTop: 120 }, 'fast', false);

    $('#back').fadeIn(5).animate({
        marginTop:90,
        marginLeft:107 }, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).on('click', function() {
                $('img.enroll').removeAttr('style').fadeOut(2);
                $(this).fadeOut(500);

    }); 
  });
});
```

this code is saying, when the mouse entered to the p20 area, enroll-en and enroll-fa and back, will be fade in. but p20 will move in a situation to another position and , I need that when you hover the mouse there, enroll-en and enroll-fa and back, don't appear with fade in...
please note that the problem is with #p20 not other elements...

Comment: I test the remove and detach for removing the texts but this functions didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try css property `pointer-events:none;`, it will stop any mouse event over the element. 
check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events for more informations about this property

Comment: Thats it... Your answer was very usefull... unfortunately I can't vote because of my reputation...

Comment: is this cross-browser?

Comment: here you can see the browsers compatibility: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events#Browser_compatibility